# Access Forbidden using Xampp with Register_Globals Off

Tags: php, xampp, register-globals

I recently learned that it is more secure to turn `register_globals` off in the `php.ini` file.

However, when using the following script, it works when `register_globals` is turned on and when `register_globals` is turned off I get a `Error 403 Access Forbidden` message after I press the submit button:

```
    <?php 
         if (isset($_POST['user']))
         {
             $user = $_POST['user'];
         }
         if (isset($_POST['address']))
         {
             $address = $_POST["address"];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
              echo "Welcome, ".$user. ". <br>";
              echo "Your address is: ".$address;
        }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Personal Info</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action = "<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
       Name: <input type="text" name="user">
       <br>
       Address: <input type="text" name="address">
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong that I get this error message only when `register_globals` is turned off. I am on Windows XP, I am using Xampp 1.7.4, and I am a noob :)

Answer (score 0):

`$PHP_SELF` must be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead. The presence of `$PHP_SELF` is a side effect of register_globals being on.

Answer (score 0):

$PHP_SELF depends on register_globals. Use

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

instead.